# Building json from tabular hierarchical data

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamic, expandoobject

Let's say I have some data as you see below:

```
{
    "Menu": {
        "aaa": "aaa",
        "bbb": {
             "ccc": "ccc",
             "ddd": "ddd"
        },
        "eee": "eee"
     }
}
```

I can save this type of hierarchical data to database in a relational way like that:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmuq1.jpg
```

Sample list:

```
    List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 1, ParentId = null, MenuName = "Menu", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 2, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "aaa", Url = "aaa", SiteId = 1 });
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 3, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "bbb", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 4, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ccc", Url = "ccc", SiteId = 1 });
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 5, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ddd", Url = "ddd", SiteId = 1 });
    menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 6, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "eee", Url = "eee", SiteId = 1 });
```

So when I get the relational data from db as a **List** of **MenuItem** objects, how can I tranlate it back to json?

```
public partial class MenuItem
{
    public int SiteMenuId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModifiedUser { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Do I have to use Dictionary or ExpandoObject or something? I want to have the the exact same format as I have at the begining.

Comment: Look up newtonsoft - http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and how to serialize to json.

Comment: Thanks Will I know about newtonsoft. But I want my json to be as same as the first format. This is what I ask actually.

Comment: I generally use Automapper to convert between the model being exposed over http and the dto.

Comment: Have you looked at [Build JSON Hierarchy from Structured Data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19256579/10263)

Comment: @BrianRogers Yes, but I don't want to have children:[] attribute in my json format. I need to have the exact same format as explained in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [Json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), we can write a custom converter to generate our desired json from list of `MenuItem`.

*NOTE: I omitted the reader part for the converter to make it concise (as its not really related to the question) but the logic would be similar to the writer part.*

```
class MenuItemJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (MenuItemCollection) || objectType==typeof(List<MenuItem>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var map=new Dictionary<int,JObject>();
        var collection = (List<MenuItem>) value;
        var root=new JObject();

        var nestedItems=collection.GroupBy(i => i.ParentId).ToLookup(g=>g.Key); //or we can simply check for item.Url==null but I believe this approach is more flexible

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item.ParentId == null)
            {
                var firstObj=new JObject();
                root.Add(item.MenuName,firstObj);
                map.Add(item.SiteMenuId,firstObj);
                continue;
            }

            var parent = map[item.ParentId.Value];

            if (!nestedItems.Contains(item.SiteMenuId))
            {
                parent.Add(item.MenuName,item.Url);
                continue;
            }

            var jObj = new JObject();
            parent.Add(item.MenuName, jObj);
            map.Add(item.SiteMenuId, jObj);
        }

        writer.WriteRaw(root.ToString());
    }
}
```

here is direct usage example:

```
        var menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 1, ParentId = null, MenuName = "Menu", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 2, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "aaa", Url = "aaa", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 3, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "bbb", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 4, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ccc", Url = "ccc", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 5, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ddd", Url = "ddd", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 6, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "eee", Url = "eee", SiteId = 1 });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(menuItems,Formatting.Indented,new MenuItemJsonConverter());
```

or we can derive from `List<>` and decorate it with `[JsonConverter(typeof(MenuItemJsonConverter))]` for more convenience:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MenuItemJsonConverter))]
class MenuItemCollection : List<MenuItem>
{      
}
```

then simply use it like:

```
        var menuItems = new MenuItemCollection();
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 1, ParentId = null, MenuName = "Menu", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 2, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "aaa", Url = "aaa", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 3, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "bbb", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 4, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ccc", Url = "ccc", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 5, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ddd", Url = "ddd", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 6, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "eee", Url = "eee", SiteId = 1 });

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(menuItems,Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object for that purpose:

```
KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>> toExport = new KeyValuePair<int, int>("Menu", new List<Object>());
```

Then, you can add elements, like this:

```
toExport.Value.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("aaa", "aaa"));
```

To add composite things to this, you can do something like that:

```
KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>> bbb = new KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>>("bbb", new List<Object>());
bbb.Value.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ccc", "ccc"));
bbb.Value.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ddd", "ddd"));
toExport.Value.Add(bbb);
```

When you have built your object, you can use NewtonSoft's [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) method.

You can also create a helper class to help you.

EDIT: Creation of dynamic data.

```
public class DynamicKeyValueBuilder {

    private KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>> toExport;

    public DynamicKeyValueBuilder(string mainKey) {
        toExport = new KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>>(mainKey, new List<Object>());
    }

    public string getJSON() {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.toExport);
    }

    private KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>> searchParent(List<string> path) {
        KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>> temp = (KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>>)this.toExport;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < path.Count) {
            try {
                temp = (KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>>)temp.First(item => item.Key == path.ElementAt(index)); //throws exception if value is not list or the element was not found
                index++;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                //handle exceptions
                return null;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //If value == null, we create a list
    public boolean addElement(List<string> path, string key, string value) {
        KeyValuePair<string, Object> parent = this.searchParent(path);
        //failure
        if (parent == null) {
            return false;
        }
        parent.Value.Add((value == null) ? (new KeyValuePair<string, List<Object>>(key, new List<Object>())) : (new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value)));
        return true;
    }

}
```

Code is untested, if you encounter errors, please, let me know instead of just down-voting, I believe I am putting an effort here to help.

You can instantiate the class like this:

```
DynamicKeyValueBuilder myBuilder = new DynamicKeyValueBuilder("Menu");
```

When you intend to add a new `<string, string>` element, you can do it like this:

```
myBuilder.Add(new List<string>(new string[] {"Menu"}), "aaa", "aaa");
```

When you intend to add a new `<string, List<Object>>` element, you can do it like this:

```
myBuilder.Add(new List<string>(new string[] {"Menu"}), "bbb", null);
```

When you intend to add something inside an inner list, you can do it like this:

```
myBuilder.Add(new List<string>(new string[] {"Menu", "bbb"}), "ccc", "ccc");
```

Comment: Thanks, ite seems that KeyValuePair objects will help me. But my main question is how can I build the appropriate object using the dynamic data. Think of the number of the items in json and depth of them will vary.

Comment: @anilca, I have edited my answer. Code is untested, let me know if you find problems in it.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand how to use your builder. I added the sample list of items to the question. If you have the sample list how do you use it to create the json I expected? And what if I have 2 root elements, something other than "Menu" in the sample?

Comment: I believe that your problem is that you did not succeed in building the List expected as path. You have a ParentId there to help you in your quest. For instance, the parent of 5 is 3, the parent of 3 is 1 and the parent of 1 is null, so 1 is root. You can build a tree using the ParentId relation, for example. There was no mention of multiple roots initially, but you can use List<DynamicKeyValueBuilder> for that purpose, or you can make toExport a List and slightly modify searchParent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use NewtonSoft, use to deserialize your JSON content and see how the resulting object looks like. Then, create a class that matches the resulting structure of the deserialization. Reverse engineering...

Use this method:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ "menu": { "aaa": "aaa"......} }");
```

Let me know your findings.

Comment: But my json will not be same everytime. Think of the number of the items in json and depth of them will vary